# How disable strict code checks in PhpStorm 2016.2.1

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

I have the latest version of PhpStorm and after the most recent update it asked me at some point if I want to enable strict checks (I believe that is what it called it). I said yes, thinking that it may be helpful. But instead it has been insanely obnoxious.

It constantly highlights when I don't use exact comparisons ('==' vs '==='). It complains on every use of the "empty()" function. And many other mundane things that are commonplace.

I have been digging around and have been unable to find the setting that enables this level of strictness in the first place. The closest I can come to finding anything is in inspections. But nothing I try is fixing it. I have even tried resetting the project settings to Global defaults. I suspect I set it Globally on accident.

Incidentally, while writing this I did finally find the reference to the "empty()" function usage and disable that warning. So now my question is does anyone know how to disable all the strict check changes and set it back to out of the box defaults?

Thanks!

Comment: alt+enter on the offending code and disable the inspection

Comment: @NDM: That works pretty well for individual inspections. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested by this blog entriy about strict_type inspection added to phpStorm for PHP 7.1 supports
https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/07/php-7-support-in-phpstorm-2016-2/

Also you can open the "Preference" of your PhpStorm and uncheck the inspection of the strict type, you can find it by typing "strict" in the search :
[Preference Inspection Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAqg8.png)

Comment: I will read up on that a bit later and get back with you. Thanks!